# how to generate combinations of key, value pairs in apache spark(scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, key, combinations

I have an RDD like this(all numbers are Int):

```
(2,List(2,2,7))
(7,List(9,7,9))
(9,List(2,7,9))
```

How do I generate an RDD such that for each list we have all possibilities of keys:

```
(2,List(2,2,7))
(7,List(2,2,7))
(9,List(2,2,7))
(2,List(9,7,9))
(7,List(9,7,9))
(9,List(9,7,9))
(2,List(2,7,9))
(7,List(2,7,9))
(9,List(2,7,9))
```

Follow up, I need to calculate the counts for each row when key value is equal to the values in the list, for example,

```
(2,List(2,2,7)) results in (2, 2) since there are two 2s in the list
(7,List(2,2,7)) results in (7, 1) since there is one 7 in the list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate all possible key-value pairs I would use something like

`rdd.map(_._1).cartesian(rdd.map(_._2))`

That gives exactly

```
(2,List(9, 7, 9))
(2,List(2, 7, 9))
(7,List(2, 2, 7))
(7,List(9, 7, 9))
(7,List(2, 7, 9))
(9,List(2, 2, 7))
(9,List(9, 7, 9))
(9,List(2, 7, 9))
(2,List(2, 2, 7))
```

For final result you can use map:

```
rdd.map(_._1).cartesian(rdd.map(_._2)).map{case (k, v) => {(k, v, v.count(_ == k))}}

(2,List(2, 2, 7),2)
(2,List(2, 7, 9),1)
(7,List(2, 7, 9),1)
(2,List(9, 7, 9),0)
(7,List(2, 2, 7),1)
(9,List(2, 2, 7),0)
(9,List(9, 7, 9),2)
(7,List(9, 7, 9),1)
(9,List(2, 7, 9),1)
```

You can exclude the list itself from the final tuples, I added it just to check if it works right. 
In terms of your problem it may be very useful to check list to be `null` and handle it in a proper way